# Saving a function in an array, and retrieving its index

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

How can I get the index of a function stored in an array? The following code returns `-1`

```
var myArray = [ function(){console.log('fct1')} ];
myArray.indexOf( function(){console.log('fct1')} );
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VKc4T/)

More details:
I'm using jQuery to delegate events. Each event has one or more callback functions to call. It's impossible for me to know what the functions are since they are not pre-coded. Each callback function will be stored in an array. When a new callback function is added, I want to verify that it isn't already in the array, to avoid duplicates which would be both called by the event.

Answer (score 1):

Any *object* in JavaScript will not be equal to something similar, except itself.

```
var func = function() {
    console.log('fct1')
};
console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(func));
# [object Function]
```

Since functions are also objects in JavaScript, you cannot search for a function *object* with another function *object* which does the same.

To be able to get a match, you need to use the same function object, like this

```
var func = function() {
    console.log('fct1')
};
var myArray = [func];
console.log(myArray.indexOf(func));
# 0
```

Comment: The problem is the function I'm trying to find will always be anonymous. Can I match it with `.toString()`? Or is this a big no-no? [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VKc4T/1/)

Comment: @Westerfaq Do you construct the array with that function?

Comment: Yes. And then I get another function and must verify if it already is in the array.

Comment: @Westerfaq Oh, then it is not possible, unless it is the same function object :'(

Comment: Well I'll just use `.toString()` then, since it seems to be working. I was hoping there would be a more conventional way to do it. Thank you

Comment: @Westerfaq But that is not recommended at all. There may be some other way to solve your actual problem. Can you please explain that in the question?

Comment: @Westerfaq: No, do not use `toString`. And it is not a problem at all, when you "get another function" it is either a different function or the *same* function that has been given previously to you - the caller (the one who hands you the functions) decides and can be held responsible. You only need to compare the references.

Comment: Okay but how can I get the reference of an anonymous function?

Answer (score 1):

This happens due to multiple references.
Each function you declared has a different reference and is not equal to the other.
That's why indexOf doesn't identify it.
Try this:

```
var func = function(){console.log('fct1')};
var myArray = [func];
alert(myArray.indexOf(func)); // will alert 0.
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Um3q/)

Comment: Not *references*, but *instances*. You could have multiple references to the same object.